# Restricting Google Groups Tag Use

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-tags

Is it possible to restrict the use of specific tags to moderators/admins only in Google Groups (e.g. "status-completed" on Meta Stack Overflow)?  I've taken a look at the Google Groups help pages and done a search on Google, but neither yielded any useful results about whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the group administrator could enable and allow certain users to enter free form tags, but no to block the use of tags.

> #### Tags
>
> Tags are special words used to associate topics with subject areas.
> Tags are created by administrators (or members with the "enter free
> form tags" permission) for the group and then applied by members to
> individual topics. For example, an administrator of a group called
> "Smart Phones" might create a tag called "android." Group members can
> assign this tag to topics in the group to identify the subject as
> relating to "android." Other group members can search on topics with
> the tag "android" to find related topics.

**References**
[Enable and create tags for a group - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1311298?hl=en)
[Permissions - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465496?hl=en)